# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln^3 n}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac{1}{\ln k\ln(n-k)\ln(n+k)\sqrt{n+k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation

On [a Chinese website](https://www.zhihu.com/question/497785198/answer/2216959403), someone has posted a solution as follows:

Notice

\begin{align*} s_n&:=\frac{\ln^3 n}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac{1}{\ln k\ln(n-k)\ln(n+k)\sqrt{n+k}}\\ &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}, \end{align*}

and define

$$a_n(k):=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln n}\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)}.$$

It's obvious that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n(k)=1$, independent of $k$.

Hence, $\forall \varepsilon\in(0,1), \exists N>0~ s.t.~1-\varepsilon\le a_n(k)\le1+\varepsilon$ holding for all $n>N,$ which implies

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{a_n(k)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}+\frac{1-\varepsilon}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\le s_n \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{a_n(k)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}+\frac{1+\varepsilon}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}.$$

Let $n \to \infty$, then
$$(1-\varepsilon)\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}}\le \liminf_{n \to \infty} s_n \le\limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n\le (1+\varepsilon)\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}}.$$

As per the arbitariness of $\varepsilon>0$, we can conclude $$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n= \int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}}=2\sqrt{2}-2.$$

**Is it correct? Does there exist any other solution?**

Comment: If $a_k(n)$ tends to $0$, who come $1-\varepsilon \leq a_k(n) \leq 1+\varepsilon$?

Comment: @GaryG Sorry,a typo. It's $1$.

Comment: For fixed $k$, $$
a_n (k) \sim \frac{{\ln n}}{{\ln k}} \to  + \infty 
$$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: @Gary Yes. You're right. He made a mistake here.

Comment: But can it be remedied？

Comment: To answer your last question, there is another proposed solution on the site you linked.